# Если у вывески нет фона, она всё равно вывеска?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, семантика

Как называются вывески, которые расположены не на щите, а состоят из отдельно расположенных на стене букв?

Answer (score 3):

**вы́весить**
1. Повесить наружу, расположить в висячем положении.
2. Поместить, повесить для обозрения, для всеобщего сведения.

В словаре Ушакова:
[вывеска](https://slovar.cc/rus/ushakov/389924.html)
1. Надпись, иногда с какими-нибудь изображениями, у магазинов, торгово-промышленных предприятий, ремесленных заведений, указывающая характер деятельности и назначения.
Вывеска магазина. Повесить вывеску. Живописец вывесок.

В толковом словаре:
**вывеска**
I. 1. Процесс действия по гл. *вывесить, вывешивать*. 2. отт. Результат такого действия.
2. Доска с надписью, рисунком, обозначающими наименование, род деятельности предприятия, учреждения и т. п.

Делаем вывод: названия различных заведений, которые расположены не на щите (не на доске, не на пластине), а состоят из самостоятельно висящих букв, — это всё равно **вывеска**.
Эти буковки — с различной конфигурацией и возможной подсветкой — к чему-то прикреплены и находятся в т. н. висячем положении.

[Виды наружных световых вывесок](https://zametno.su/365638/)
[Виды рекламных вывесок](https://artafa.com.ua/tafa-blog/vidy-reklamnyh-vyvesok/)

Answer (score 1):

Такой тип вывесок в России называется "Объемные буквы". Или чуть реже - "Световые буквы" - https://www.mediagrad.ru/obemnye_bukvy